# simple json retrieval

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I know this is an old chestnut but I want to do this *without* importing newton-soft or json.net

I know this should work

this is the json :

```
{ "do": "Thing", "with": "abc" }
```

literally that's it. I need to get this into c# land

this is what I have so far

```
var json = wc.DownloadString("url");
Console.WriteLine("GOT >> " + json); //says GOT >> { "do": "Thing", "with": "abc" }
var sJson = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var data = sJson.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(json); //crashes with No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
```

what is the leanest least bloated way possible way that I can get `data["do"]` and `data["with"]` from my single line json? It will only ever return one thing ... if I have to string walk it I will but it shouldn't be this hard

Comment: Why `Dictionary<string, string>[]` array? What you have is a `Dictionary<string, string>` at best

Comment: because "do" and "with", but come to think of it I don't need that, originally there was a array in there for with and I chopped it up a bit

Comment: I did it like this in the end `Do data = sJson.Deserialize<Do>(json);` where `Do` was simply `public string todo = "";  public string with = "";` still seems highly sub-optimal but hey ho

Comment: "do" and "with" what? :) There's no array in your sample JSON, so it corresponds to `Dictionary<string, string>`, "do" and "with" being the keys and "Thing" and "abc" being their corresponding values.

Comment: @MrHeelis check [provided answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53988121/5233410)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a backing class for the data

```
public class Data {
    public string do { get; set; }
    public string with { get; set; }
}
```

and simply desrialize to that

```
var data = sJson.Deserialize<Data>(json);
```

If the provided data is in fact an array then update the generic return type accordingly

Answer (score 3):

There's no array in your JSON, just a simple object so it can be deserialized to a single `Dictionary` instance. Simply change `Dictionary<string, string>[]` to `Dictionary<string, string>`. Like this:

```
var data = sJson.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

You can then access your values like this:

```
data["do"] // returns "Thing"
data["with"] // returns "abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is the problem. Try this ([Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p5naoR)):

```
var json = "{ \"do\": \"Thing\", \"with\": \"abc\" }";
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
Console.WriteLine(data["do"]);
Console.WriteLine(data["with"]);
```

output

```
Thing
abc
```

Note that I am using Json.NET here as written in the documentation:

> Json.NET should be used for serialization and deserialization. Provides serialization and deserialization functionality for AJAX-enabled applications.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: The author wrote at the beginning of his question: _I want to do this without importing newton-soft or json.net_ ;)

Comment: Oh I missed it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Regex :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "{ \"do\": \"Thing\", \"with\": \"abc\" }";
            string pattern = "\"(?'key'[^\"]+)\":\\s+\"(?'value'[^\"]+)";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = matches.Cast<Match>()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["key"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```